# Хочу создать бота в дискорде но заинтересовался языком программирование

Tags: discord

**Всем здравствуйте! Я совсем зелёный в языке программирование а если быть точнее, я ничего не знаю, но у меня сильное желание создать что-то своё и научиться.**

**Начнём с того, что у меня все плохо с математикой можно сказать, то что это для меня является стеной.
Я заинтересовался созданием бота в дискорде и мне нужна помощь а конкретно совет с чего начать, какой язык программирование и так далее.
Я буду дико благодарен всем, кто откликнется.**

Comment: Начни с чтения книг

Comment: и после этого посмотри на python. хоть я и ненавижу питон,  он будет удобнее вначале.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский с русским норм. наверное, читает

Comment: Какие книги можете порекомендовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*К сожалению, этот вопрос, скорее всего, закроют, как "**невозможно дать объективный ответ**"*

### Python

Пайтон хорош, как простой и удобный язык для новичков. На нём можно писать ботов-администраторов, чат-ботов и даже текстовых помощников. Об этом читайте [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/511454/). Ну или [тут](https://pythobyte.com/create-a-discord-bot-with-python-c91b9549/) :)

### Javascript

Нет опыта программирования ботов на JS, но знаю, что он хорош в этом. Нашёл об этом [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/507948/) для новичков.

И кстати, [вот](https://lolz.guru/threads/1718941/) почти такой же вопрос на **lolz.guru**

> Ну так вот, до какой степени я должен знать математики и важна ли она?

Да. Программирование - это в основном информатика, а информатика основана на математике. Вы должны знать хотя бы азы математики, чтобы заняться программированием. Иначе вы будете писать код, но не понимать, на чём он основан и как работает.

Comment: Возможно дать объективный ответ на мой вопрос невозможно, но все-же советы были и за это я вам благодарен. Остаётся вопрос:

Я знаю, что python востребованный язык, и знаю что рано или поздно потребуется знание математики. Ну так вот, до какой степени я должен знать математики и важна ли она?

Comment: @Takenji добавил. Если помог ответ, поставьте галочку ;)